# Scrollbar in ui grid

Tags: angular, ui-grid

I have a `Ui-grid` `scrollbar` which does not work until all of the data is loaded.

I tried changing these options:

```
enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
enableVerticalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: What does not work? Can you describe what you expect and what you see instead? Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When page is loaded and a table begin to appear I want to scroll it, but scroll doesn't work unltil all rows is loaded. No errors in console.